# Как с помощью RESТ запросов сделать запрос на переход по странице

Tags: java, xml, rest

Я могу получить, в виде запроса вывод web страницы. И хочу получить ссылки (либо вкладки) на внутренние страницы web-ресурса.

Метод которым я хочу это получить :1. делаю запрос на XML форму. 2. в виде XML-кода получаю ссылку. 3 приказываю зайти на эту ссылку. 
Цель что бы машина зашла на адрес "http://n7701-sys274:2990/jira/" (выполнено), прочла web-ресурс (выполнено), перешла на страницу "http://localhost:2990/jira/projects/" (не выполнено).

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    // 1. create a client
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    // 2. set a target to client
    WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://n7701-sys274:2990/jira/").build());
    // getting XML data
    //System.out.println(service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
    System.out.println(service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class));
         }
  }
```

Не знаю что делать.

Comment: А выслать ответ с Redirect не подойдет?

Comment: @Uraty можно в виде кода,  пожалуйста. А то я не понимаю как и  о чём речь.

Comment: Извиняюсь, подумал что сервер тоже вы пишете. Тогда вам нужно посмотреть на то, что выводает в ответе сервер. Вы не прикрепили его в вопросе. Дальше нужно парсить этот ответ либо стандартными средствами для обработки XML, либо по быстрому набросать в виде Regexp. Хотите код - прикрепите резульатт вывода: `System.out.println(service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class));`